Quick search list of tuples
I have a very long list of tuples, about 4000 entries. Data is not sorted. This is not the full code. It is a simplified example. Just looking for a way to speed this up if possible.
arr = [['863', '0.31', '0.00', '0.69'], ['621', '1.00', '0.00', '0.00'], ['834', '1.00', '0.00', '0.00']]

etc
I'm running a loop to compare a text file with 40000 entries and I need to search the array above for matches. The best I have come up with us using a numpy array:
nparr = np.asarray(arr)
lines = []

for i in range(40000): #a simplified version of loop which has varying values in orignal
    ind = np.where(nparr == '834') #varies in original
    item = nparr[ind[0][0]]
    lines.append(item[0])

Write out results
with open("output.txt", "w", buffering=8192) as file:
    file.writelines(lines)

On my windows machine the loop takes about 1.3s, and the writeout takes 0.02s. For some reason on a linux machine that has better specs the loop takes 2x longer. I have narrowed the speed drop to the np.where function.
Is there a way to speed this up wihtout np.where or am I at max speed here?
Thanks

Can you give an example input and output? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why do you loop 40k times to do the same thing?

This is a simplified version of the code. I'm comparing the list to a text file with 40000 lines. The code above works. I'm just looking for aways to speed up or replace the np.where function to retrieve the index of the item I'm after in the smaller list.

np.where is very optimized (I am the one who did it) and I do not expect much people to write a much faster version than the current one (especially not in Python). However, one issue here is that the array has only few items in the last axis and Numpy is not generally optimized for that. Besides, UTF-8 string comparison is generally not very fast. Do you really need a string comparison? Moreover, what you really want is not clear and I wonder if the algorithm you use is the best. Last but not least, more threads might help to reach better performance regarding the actual real-world problem

Thus, please provide a code closer to the real-world one since details matter for performance.

@Jérôme I believe '834' is varying at each step. Indeed the example should be improved.

@JérômeRichard, this is a complicated project that is using AI and returning AI probabilities and I have to output to text. There is no way around that. As I said, this is a simplified version of the problem that highlights the specific issue I'm having which is that np.where is seemingly much slower on linux. It does run fine how it is on windows for some reason. I'm doing an index lookup to compare two lists using np.wehre. I just need the index value for '834', which varies in the original code.

@JérômeRichard, converting '834' into an int didn't speed it up on linux but it did speed it up on windows. Not sure what is going on there. Linux: compile file array:  3.13  seconds, windows: Compile file array:  0.81  seconds. The linux machine has a 4.8ghz processor, the windows machine has a 2.4ghz processor.

@JérômeRichard, I'm not sure why this is going so much slower on linux, I'll be running this as part of pipeline that runs on data upwards of 1200+ times a night. If I can get it down to the windows speeds (0.8s vs 3s) it will speed up the processing by almost an hour over the course of the night.

the timing on Linux vs Windows are dependent of the compiler used to compile the types, the standard library (especially for np.where), and also the default type due to the ABI. you can fix the problem if the last point is the problem : you just need to ensure the types are the same on both platform by specifying it explicitly/manually. If the problem is due to the other points, there is nothing to do apart from optimizing the Numpy code further.

@JérômeRichard The code before was working acceptable, was just confused why the performance of np.where was so different between the systems. I was able to get it working much faster using dictionaries so it's a non-issue now. thanks :)

@Rankinstudio For np.where specifically, it should use 64-integer on Linux and 32-bit on Windows. Bigger types tends to cause the target memory area to fill be bigger and thus to results in a longer execution time. The target array is also bigger and the time of allocations are dependent of their size. This is something dependent of the C ABI. You cannot change it from CPython (this requires at least a rebuild of Numpy).

As for the dictionary, the operation is performed in O(1) while it is O(n) for np.where not to mention the np.where solution need to iterate on values too. This is certainly why dictionary are faster. The solution you provide is for a more specific problem (ie. easier to solve) than the one stated in the question. I think it would have been better to provide this information from the beginning so that we could have helped you better ;) .

Your example doesn't really make sense since the loop is doing the same thing over and over.
I'll assume that in real life nparr == '834' has varying values.
Instead of using a loop, you could test all values at once. First build a target list/array based on all your files, which will contain all values to test, then perform the search only once with numpy.isin. For example:
targets = ['834', '621']

m = np.isin(nparr, targets)
line = nparr[m.any(axis=1), 0]

Output:
['621', '834']

If you can have multiple matches per row and want all of them:
idx = np.where(np.isin(nparr.ravel(), targets))[0]//nparr.shape[1]

line = nparr[idx, 0]

If order matters, you might also want to use pandas and merge.

Yes, as I explained in the post this is a simplified version of the original code highlighting the problem. The loop has varying values. I'm trying to have it return the index of the location of '834', not '834' itself. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

And order doesn't matter at all, it's an unsorted list.

line = nparr[m.any(axis=1), :] also returns what I'm after, but it's slower than np.where on linux.
3.07s  np.where 3.42s isin. Also a tad slower on windows.

I'm not quite sure what the issue with numpy is on linux here. It ran about 3x faster on a windows machine that is 1/2 as fast as the linux machine. By eliminating all numpy in the loop I was able to get the speeds from 3s down to 1.5s on the linux machine.
Instead of a numpy array, I built a custom dictionary with the item I was interested in as the key and the AI probabilities as the values like so:
arrdict = {'863': ['0.31', '0.00', '0.69'], '621': ['1.00', '0.00', '0.00'], '834': ['1.00', '0.00', '0.00']}

etc
lines = []

for i in range(40000): #a simplified version of loop which has varying values in orignal
    item = arrdict['834'] #this varies in original code
    lines.append(item[:])

This solution is about 2x slower on windows than the np.where solution, and about 2x faster on linux than the np.where solution. No idea why.
